# MinGW standard library missing any.h?

Tags: c++, mingw

I recently downloaded mingw from http://www.mingw.org/ and installed its c++ compiler and dependencies, which include installing standard library headers.  I have also successfully compiled a hello world program, compilation is fine, and common old headers are there and work fine (such as `string.h`).

However, when I attempted to `#include <any>`, it threw an error that `any.h` does not exist.  And sure enough, when I look in `mingw\include\`, there is no `any.h` (and I see other things missing, such as `variant.h`).

I've looked through the mingw package manager, and I have the standard library stuff installed, and there's nothing else relevant to install.  Does minGW support C++17?  If so, how can I get these newer header files?  It seems like this should be something really obvious.

Comment: g++ version outputs 6.3.0.  I see that `shared_mutex` should be supported by gcc 6, but I don't see it in the mingw include directory either.

Comment: `<any>` wasn't added until 7.x (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need mingw-w64, which provides more recent GCC versions:

http://mingw-w64.org

You can find a 7.2.0 download here:

http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds

Answer (score 0):

The any feature requires C++17 support, so if your compiler  implementation actually does support it, you probably want to specify it on the command line like this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 a.cpp
```

Of course, this requires a modern C++ compiler, like that you can get from nuwen.net.

Comment: My IDE is setup to compile with c++17, but the actual `any.h` file is missing from the mingw install.  Other older standard library headers, such as `string.h`, `map.h`, etc are there but the `any.h` doesn't even exist.

Comment: The nuwen.net distribution will compile the header - whether or not it fully implements the functionality, I couldn't say. And there is no any.h. Those are C header files.